# linq filter columns rather than data

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

Firstly, I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible or not so apologies if I'm asking a stupid question.

So I am able to filter a DataTable using linq to get the data I need, I'm wondering if it's possible to filter the columns using a simlar statement.

For example if I have the below datatable `dtMyData`

| ID | Name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Conor | 100 | 87 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Frank | 35 | 70 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Jeff | 35 | 13 | 0 | 57 |

I can filter it to the below using the following statement

```
dtMyData = dtMyData.AsEnumerable().Where(Function (f) f("Name").ToString().Equals("Frank")).CopyToDataTable
```

| ID | Name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Frank | 35 | 70 | 0 | 0 |

What I'm wanting to do (If it's possible) is filter the columns in a similar way so that I can select all of the columsn > 2 plus the first 2 columns. Giving me the following columns

| ID | Name | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Conor | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Frank | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Jeff | 0 | 57 |

Comment: Based on your examples it looks like you want to copy the original table and drop columns (with title) 1 and 2. Is that statement more or less correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. each time I run the code the filter would be different potentially so I want to use a variable to control what I filter the columns on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this method:

```vb
Private Function CopyTable(source As DataTable, columnsToKeep As IEnumerable(Of String)) As DataTable
    Dim copiedTable As DataTable = source.Clone()
    Dim columnsToRemove() As DataColumn = copiedTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).Where(Function(column) Not columnsToKeep.Contains(column.ColumnName)).ToArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To columnsToRemove.Length - 1
        copiedTable.Columns.Remove(columnsToRemove(i))
    Next
    For Each row As DataRow In source.Rows
        Dim values As New List(Of Object)
        For Each column As DataColumn In copiedTable.Columns
            values.Add(row.Item(column.ColumnName))
        Next
        copiedTable.Rows.Add(values.ToArray())
    Next
    Return copiedTable
End Function
```

What this does is

1. Clone the DataTable
2. Loop over the copied DataTable and remove the columns that are not in the `columnsToKeep`
3. Loop over the original DataTable and add the rows to the copied DataTable without the cells that are not in the `columnsToKeep`

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2l6wk9

**Edit**

It would actually be easier to use `DataTable.Copy` over `DataTable.Clone`, my apologies:

```vb
Private Function CopyTable(source As DataTable, columnsToKeep As IEnumerable(Of String)) As DataTable
    Dim copiedTable As DataTable = source.Copy()
    Dim columnsToRemove() As DataColumn = copiedTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).Where(Function(column) Not columnsToKeep.Contains(column.ColumnName)).ToArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To columnsToRemove.Length - 1
        copiedTable.Columns.Remove(columnsToRemove(i))
    Next
    Return copiedTable
End Function
```

What this updated code does is:

1. Copy the DataTable with its data
2. Loop over the copied DataTable and remove the columns that are not in the `columnsToKeep`

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NEIm2t